# Middleware to convert IDs to slug

Tags: php, laravel

I've got 90% of my site finished, up until now it's been passing round model IDs from page to page as such:

```
http://website.domain/2/content/3
```

I'm using models bound within the web.php like so:

```
Route::get('{post}/content/{comment}', 'ContentController@index');
```

This is working fine.

I would like to change the URL so it's more user/SEO friendly so it displays as such:

```
http://website.domain/hello-world/content/this-is-more
```

I know I can do a look-up in the controller for every index, however I was wondering if there was a more automated way to convert the URL when an ID is used, such as a middleware perhaps, or is doing a look-up everytime I need to do it the only way forward?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using a package for this, like [Laravel Sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable), which covers lots of edge cases like conflicting slug names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to do that through middleware...

The Eloquent's models has a method that indicates what column will be used by the router to lookup the binded model, you just need to override it.

Example for the post's model:

```
namespace App\Models\Post;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName(): string {
        $identifier = Route::current()->parameters()['post'];

        if (!ctype_digit($identifier)) {
            return 'your-slug-col-name';
        }

        return 'id';
    }
}
```

This way your route will work with id or slug...

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is use explicit model binding

in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php in method boot you can define your bindings

For ex:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('postSlug',function($value){
       return Post::whereSlug($value)->firstOrFail();
    });
    Route::bind('commentSlug',function($value){
       return Comment::whereSlug($value)->firstOrFail();
    });

    parent::boot();
}
```

and in your **Route.php**:

```
Route::get('{postSlug}/content/{commentSlug}', 'ContentController@index');
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: Best answer so far